# how can I get these functions from a different defined class?

Tags: python, tkinter

so my code takes 2 date ranges and selects dates that fall in-between them. so the dates are stored in entry frames in Tkinter using this code:

```
def main():
import tkinter as tk
    e1 = tk.Entry(frame)
    e1.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 0.25,relheight = 0.25)
    e1.pack()

    e2 = tk.Entry(frame)
    e2.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 0.25,relheight = 0.25)
    e2.pack()
b1 = tk.Button(frame, text = "enter", command = button_command)
```

e1 is the first date and e2 is the second date which the user can enter. and when the enter button is pressed it activated the button command function as seen below:

```
def button_command():
    date1 = e1.get()
    date2 = e2.get()
```

however when I print either of the dates it returns a none value. (a value that just says 'none'. does anybody know why. I think its something to do with the classes as I have tried it without defining main and it works fine. however the way I need to implement it in to my project requires it to be under `def main()` however this has messed up how the code works with the none values. so yeah if anybody could help me out it would be great :)

Comment: If what you want to achieve is the ability for certain part of the code to only execute if the file is running as a main file, and not when imported as a module, then that behavior can be achieved in python using the `if __name__ == '__main__' : ` construct, under the body of which the previous body of the main function can be placed.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are packing and placing the entry widget, but only one of them is enough for it to be visible on the screen.

Comment: And, in the code provided the button is not being packed/placed/gridded to the window.

Comment: `e1` and `e2` are local variables inside `main()`, so they cannot be accessed outside `main()`.

Comment: @acw1668 so how can I change that?

Comment: The simple way is to add `global e1, e2` at the beginning of `main()` to make them global variables.